# How to map metallic texture in .mtl file?

Tags: textures, blender, wavefront, mtl-file

I have a model I must keep in .obj format. It is accompanied by 5 texture maps (Diffuse, Emissive, Normal, occlusion, and metal).

I want to reference these textures in the .mtl file but can't seem to find the syntax for that. As of right now, all I know is that to map the diffuse texture I do:

```
map_Kd Model_diffuse.png
map_Ke Model_emissive.png
map_Ka Model_occlusion.png
```

But I can't find any other keywords for mapping the metal texture type. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I found out [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file#Physically-based_Rendering) that you can used `map_Pm` for the metallic